# Ajax - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, streaming

I'm trying to work with the [Livestream API](http://www.livestream.com/userguide/?title=Guide_API#Retrieve_Channels) to see if a certain channel is live but keep getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://channel.api.livestream.com/1.0/livestatus?channel=huskystarcraft. Origin http://www.webdevstl.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Do I need to run it through PHP or am I doing something wrong in my ajax call? It's pretty straight forward code:

```
function getActive(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {   
            var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(json);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://channel.api.livestream.com/1.0/livestatus?channel=huskystarcraft", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
getActive();
```

Comment: Are you developing on a server or locally?

Comment: Server, I don't think server calls work locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into restrictions imposed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short, AJAX calls to a different domain are prohibited and will fail - unless explicitly permitted by the remote host.

You need to either use JSONP (mostly applicable to data returned by APIs) or [proxy the request through your own server/domain](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).

CORS would also be an option, but that assumes you having access to the remote server's config.

Comment: Can't use jquery. So running it though PHP won't help at all?

Comment: The problem (and the solution linked in my answer) isn't specific to jQuery. Routing the data through a proxy of any sort (including PHP) will solve the issue - provided that the proxy is reachable from the same domain.