# How can i insert into my website a HTML source code without being modified?

Tags: html, iframe, pre

In a section of my webpage is displayed a source code of a HTML (with a `<body>`, a `<head>`, ALL that can have a HTML code), and the user can extract the code. I have that code in a text file into a iframe. The problem: Iframe doesn't works in browsers like IE8, because in modern browsers like Chrome, they insert a `<pre>` within the iframe, and IE8 doesn't.

I need a way for insert the code in the document, without the browser execute the code. Yes, there isn't necessary that the code must be in a text file (.txt), i have seen some people that set a code within a `<textarea>` and i like that. The idea is that the source code must not be modified, and i have read some PHP solutions, but i can't modify the PHP. I have tried with a `<pre>` and a `<code>`, but.. doesn't works, the browser execute the source code anyway, maybe i don't understand the correct use of that tags.

I have read that sometimes is necessary replace some special characters like `<` for `&#60;`, could be that the problem? exist a converter that will not affect the final result when be displayed?
Thanks! I don't know if i explain me good, i am open to any suggestion (sorry if i sound weird, english is not my native language)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565822/insert-html-into-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can use AJAX to fetch the file with the source code, and then use the `.text(var_with_the_code)` in a jQuery object to display HTML source code without "executing" it.

Here is a limited demo in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gberger/T3JDJ/

Comment: It works fine in JSfiddle, thanks! but i didn't mention that it was for  tumblr, and i put the next code for a test (before the </head> tag):

<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#buttonthing").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://static.tumblr.com/36bnqm6/NAFmjb014/chirimoya_beta.txt',
       success: function(data){
           $("#thediv").text(data)
       },
       error: function(error){
           alert('Uh oh, some error occurred.');   
       }
    });
});

</script>

And that didn't work, you can see it [here](http://fruitzo.tumblr.com/sdf) do you know what can be?

Comment: It says this: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://static.tumblr.com/36bnqm6/NAFmjb014/chirimoya_beta.txt. Origin http://fruitzo.tumblr.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124538/ajax-access-control-allow-origin-error

Comment: Ok, i will try to modify the PHP (because in tumblr you can't) or try to upload the file in the same origin (fruitzo.tumblr.com/......) it was very helpful, thanks for your help!